# This patent should not be granted; already published

Tags: prior-art-request, ca2815417a1

In reference to the patent: [CA2815417A1](https://www.google.com/patents/CA2815417A1)

This method was already described in a public forum on: 
    06 February 2012 - 05:30 PM
prior to the priority date of this patent.

See post #10 on this page:

https://web.archive.org/web/20120702053335/http://forums.microcash.org/index.php/topic/538-rfc-solidcoin-204-and-txfees-help-finding-a-solution/

There are two patents that are effected by this.

Answer (score 0):

That is a patent **application**, not a granted patent.

The USPTO provides a method for 3rd parties to [submit prior art before a patent is issued](http://www.uspto.gov/patent/initiatives/third-party-preissuance-submissions). It appears that [Canada does as well](https://www.patexia.com/feed/canadian-court-provides-new-relevance-for-third-party-submissions-during-patent-prosecution-114):

> Section 34.1 of the Patent Act permits third parties to file any prior art with the Commissioner which the third party believes to bear on the patentability of a pending claim, similar to subsection 122(e) of Title 35 as amended by the America Invents Act.